# Download problems

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu with kernel 3.0.0-19.33-generic. The system crashed after an upload.  It opens to a white screen now. I get an error report (error 2, No such directory or file). I have tried to install Ubuntu 12.10, it fails.  Where do I go from here? Do need to reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `chroot` (use Desktop Live CD, see the reference on bottom) into the current system and backup all your data, for example

- /etc
- /home (if it is a separate partition, just leave it and don't reformat it when you re-install)
- `dpkg --get-selections > pkg_list.txt` (list of installed packages, sometimes you forget what you have installed)

After backing up data, you can go ahead and re-install Ubuntu (re-format / partition, if /home is on the same partition, data will be gone, that's why you need to backup).

NOTE: I don't understand how you got into the situation, is it a virtual machine? What did the "upload" do? Did you see the GRUB2 menu? When did you see the white screen and error?

chroot
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot